# not able to replot the bar chart properly

Tags: jqplot

I have a jqplot as given below

```
var s1 = [200, 600, 700];
var s2 = [460, -210, 690];

var ticks = ['CENTER 1', 'CENTER 2', 'CENTER 3'];
plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [s1, s2], {

seriesDefaults: {
    renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
    rendererOptions: { fillToZero: true }
    },

axes: {
    xaxis: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
        ticks: ticks
    },

yaxis: { pad: 1.05 }
    }

});
plot1.legend.show = false;
```

When I try to replot the graph by setting `plot1.series[0].data` and `plot1.series[1].data`  it is ploting only "CENTER 1" Tick.

Could anybody please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You heading down the right path:

it just when you update the `plot1.series[0].data` the you need to provide an array of data with [[x,y],[x,y]] in this format.
I think you are just providing values right now.

[Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/QpppX/1/)

```
var s1 = [260, 600, 700];
var s2 = [460, -250, 690];

var ticks = ['CENTER 1', 'CENTER 2', 'CENTER 3'];
plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [s1, s2], {

seriesDefaults: {
    renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
    rendererOptions: { fillToZero: true }
    },

axes: {
    xaxis: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
        ticks: ticks
    },

yaxis: { pad: 1.05 }
    }

});
plot1.legend.show = false;

var s3 = [[1,200], [2,-200],[3, 200]];
plot1.series[0].data = s3;
plot1.replot(true);
```